# Как преобразовать объёмную однолистовую книгу .xlsm в csv?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, csv

Здравствуйте!
Имеется файл в формате .xlsm. В нём находится один лист. Надо преобразовать в .csv с разделителем-запятой.
Пробовал PHPExcel, но он не работает с файлом .xlsm размером 10 МБ (выпадает по таймауту). На маленьких всё нормально.

Собственно, делаю вот этой функцией:

```
function convertXLStoCSV($infile,$outfile)
{
    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);    

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($outfile);
}
```

Comment: Ну, можно пропробовать распаковать файл и рабоать с xml данными напрямую, будет быстрее и по времени и меньше по памяти, ведь `.xlsm` это обычный `zip` архив

Comment: Можно распаковывать прямо методами класса ZipArchive?

Comment: да, можно распаковать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда сталкивался со схожей задачей (прайсы автомагазина, до 50 мег), проще оказалось набросать скрипт на питоне с использованием библиотеки xlrd (заявлена поддержка xls, xlsx, не думаю, что xlsm будет проблемой). Причем потребление памяти в разы меньше, а работает секунды.

Перед вызовом сохраняем файл, используем system() или что больше нравится, потом забираем файл.

Пример взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884353/xls-to-csv-convertor)

```
import xlrd
 import csv

 def csv_from_excel():

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('your_workbook.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()
```